# extracting data from server to client via the http call. error like "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file has been blocked by CORS po"

Tags: xmlhttprequest

i have fetching data from server to report via the http call. while generating report i am having error in chrome like "zone.js:2990 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'file:///E:/Report_things/templates%20with%20single%20grade/sample.json' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https." so that sometimes i can able to see the data in report. most of the time the data is not coming. whatever it is the error is came in chrome console.if the data got fetched before this error. data was reflected in report. if data got fetched after this error, data is not got rendered in report. please help me to avoid this error.